# Why does \usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern} change the italic font to a slanted font?

Tags: fonts, italic, lmodern, slanted

I love using the `lighttt` variant of `lmodern` to get bold-faced keywords when using the typewriter font. The problem is that it appears to overwrite the default italic style with a "slanted" italic rather than a true italic. Is there any way to reverse this setting?

MWE (with the problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\textit{Hi there, how are you?}}
\end{document}
```

MWE (without the problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\textit{Hi there, how are you?}}
\end{document}
```

Below are images of the problem (on the above) and without (on the below).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look in `lmodern.sty`, we find the `lighttt` option

```
\DeclareOption{lighttt}{%
  \let\lmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
}
```

If we then examine the file `ot1lmtt.fd`, we find it used conditionally to set up the font family:

```
\ifx\lmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
% macro defined, so we use the light variant as medium (m), and
...
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{sb}{it}
     {<-> rm-lmtti10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{sb}{sl}
     {<-> rm-lmtto10}{}
...
```

So when you switch to the semi-bold weight with this option, you get different fonts for italic and oblique.

```
%%%%%%%% light (l), light condensed (lc), and dark (b) variants:
...
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{it}
     {<->sub*lmtt/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{sl}
     {<-> rm-lmtlo10}{}
...
```

but this shows you will get oblique substituted for italic when using regular weight. I take it this means there is no italic in this weight. Oblique in a matching weight is considered the best option.

```
\else
% usual setup of variants:
...
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{it}
     {<-> rm-lmtti10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{sl}
     {<-> rm-lmtto10}{}
...
```

Without the `lighttt` option, this shows you'll get distinct italic and oblique fonts in regular (`m`) weight.

```
%%%%%%%% light (l), light condensed (lc), and dark (b) variants:
...
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{l}{it}
     {<->sub*lmtt/l/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{l}{sl}
     {<-> rm-lmtlo10}{}
...
```

But if you switch to the light weight (`l`), you'll again get oblique substituted for italic.

So the technical answer is due to those lines in the `.fd` file. However, the reason those lines are written that way is that italic typewriter is not available in all weights. Regardless of `lighttt` or not, the package uses the italic when `itshape` is requested, if available, and substitutes the oblique otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a way to have the non-slanted italic shape while using `lighttt`? It's fine if it uses the italic shape from the non `lighttt` option of `lmodern`. I don't want to use `xfakebold` because that requires me to have to change all of my code listings, of which there are thousands...

Comment: @TheProgrammer So you want to always use the regular-weight italic, regardless of whether you've asked for bold or not?

Comment: Well, ideally, I'd like the regular-weight italic font to *not* be bold, in conjunction with the regular font from `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}`.

Comment: @TheProgrammer ?? If you mean, ideally you'd like the actual fonts to be different, you need a font designer ;). Do you especially need the `lighttt` option in the first place? What about an alternative to Latin Modern?

Comment: @TheProgrammer I use Latin Modern most of the time, though not with `lmodern`. My package makes the same (standard) substitutions of oblique for italic etc., but you select the weights in different ways. (I don't have the package option switch the way `lmodern` does.) But I imagine that would be less than helpful to you.

Comment: @TheProgrammer The real answer is that you can set the fonts up to do what you want, but you'd need  to modify the `.fd` files and, possibly, the `.sty` for whatever encodings you want to use. If you don't rename them, you can't distribute them so your file will produce different output elsewhere. If you rename them, you can modify them, but your document won't compile at all elsewhere without the modified files.

Comment: @TheProgrammer So you'd probably want to do the redefinitions in the preamble of your document. But I wouldn't recommend this. You are likely to find you end up with unintended effects you like less than the original issue.

Comment: There is `lmmono10-italic.otf` in the tt set. No bold.

Comment: @cfr The main reason I’m using the lighttt version of lmodern is because I need to distinguish between certain keywords in a programming language code listing. The normal lmodern (or typewriter) font doesn’t provide a distinction between bold and non-bold, but it does give the nice-looking italics. The light variant solves the former problem but introduces the latter.

Comment: @TheProgrammer Do you mean the difference between bold and non-bold monowidth typewriter isn't sufficiently obvious without the `lighttt` version? It uses different fonts but, at least on my screen, it's pretty hard to tell the bold from not at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, and if it helps, in OpenType, in TT monospaced or proportional width, there is no bold italic. (`/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/`)

[image: LMTT]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\balla{\tikz \shade (0,0) circle (1ex);}
\newcommand\ballb{\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball,ball color=blue!20] (0,0) circle (0.8ex);}
\newcommand\ball{\ballb}


%---
\setmainfont[
Path=C:/.../texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/,
%Extension=.otf,
UprightFont=lmroman12-regular.otf,
BoldFont=lmroman12-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=lmroman12-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
SlantedFont=lmromanslant12-regular.otf,
BoldSlantedFont=lmromanslant10-bold.otf,
SwashFont=lmromandunh10-regular.otf,
%BoldSwashFont=***,
FontFace={m}{swsl}{Font=lmromandunh10-oblique.otf},
FontFace={m}{unsl}{Font=lmromanunsl10-regular.otf},
FontFace={sc}{n}{Font=lmromandemi10-regular.otf},
FontFace={sc}{sl}{Font=lmromandemi10-oblique.otf},
UprightFeatures={
        SmallCapsFont={lmromancaps10-regular.otf},
        },
SlantedFeatures={
        SmallCapsFont={lmromancaps10-oblique.otf},
        },
]{Latin Modern Roman}


\DeclareRobustCommand\scseries{\fontseries{sc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsc}{\scseries}



\DeclareRobustCommand\swslshape{\fontshape{swsl}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textswsl}{\swslshape}
\DeclareRobustCommand\unslshape{\fontshape{unsl}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textunsl}{\unslshape}


%-----

\setsansfont[
Path=C:/.../texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/,
%Extension=.otf,
UprightFont=lmsans12-regular.otf,
BoldFont=lmsans10-bold.otf,
%ItalicFont=lmroman12-italic.otf,
%BoldItalicFont=lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
SlantedFont=lmsans12-oblique.otf,
BoldSlantedFont=lmsans10-boldoblique.otf,
%SwashFont=lmromandunh10-regular.otf,
%BoldSwashFont=***,
FontFace={m}{quot}{Font=lmsansquot8-regular.otf},
FontFace={b}{quot}{Font=lmsansquot8-bold.otf},
FontFace={m}{quotsl}{Font=lmsansquot8-oblique.otf},
FontFace={b}{quotsl}{Font=lmsansquot8-boldoblique.otf},
FontFace={sc}{n}{Font=lmsansdemicond10-regular.otf},
FontFace={sc}{sl}{Font=lmsansdemicond10-oblique.otf},
%UprightFeatures={
%       SmallCapsFont={lmromancaps10-regular.otf},
%       },
%SlantedFeatures={
%       SmallCapsFont={lmromancaps10-oblique.otf},
%       },
]{Latin Modern Sans}

\DeclareRobustCommand\quotshape{\fontshape{quot}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textquot}{\quotshape}
\DeclareRobustCommand\quotslshape{\fontshape{quotsl}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textquotsl}{\quotslshape}

%---

\setmonofont[
Path=C:/.../texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/,
%Extension=.otf,
UprightFont=lmmono12-regular.otf,
%BoldFont=lmsans10-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=lmmono10-italic.otf,
%BoldItalicFont=lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
SlantedFont=lmmonoslant10-regular.otf,
BoldSlantedFont=lmsans10-boldoblique.otf,
%SwashFont=lmromandunh10-regular.otf,
%BoldSwashFont=***,
%FontFace={m}{quot}{Font=lmsansquot8-regular.otf},
%FontFace={b}{quot}{Font=lmsansquot8-bold.otf},
%FontFace={m}{quotsl}{Font=lmsansquot8-oblique.otf},
%FontFace={b}{quotsl}{Font=lmsansquot8-boldoblique.otf},
FontFace={lc}{n}{Font=lmmonoltcond10-regular.otf},
FontFace={lc}{sl}{Font=lmmonoltcond10-oblique.otf},
FontFace={l}{n}{Font=lmmonolt10-regular.otf},
FontFace={l}{sl}{Font=lmmonolt10-oblique.otf},
FontFace={lb}{n}{Font=lmmonolt10-bold.otf},
FontFace={lb}{sl}{Font=lmmonolt10-boldoblique.otf},
FontFace={prop}{n}{Font=lmmonoprop10-regular.otf},
FontFace={prop}{sl}{Font=lmmonoprop10-oblique.otf},
FontFace={propl}{n}{Font=lmmonoproplt10-regular.otf},
FontFace={propl}{sl}{Font=lmmonoproplt10-oblique.otf},
FontFace={proplb}{n}{Font=lmmonoproplt10-bold.otf},
FontFace={proplb}{sl}{Font=lmmonoproplt10-boldoblique.otf},
UprightFeatures={
        SmallCapsFont={lmmonocaps10-regular.otf},
        },
SlantedFeatures={
        SmallCapsFont={lmmonocaps10-oblique.otf},
        },
]{Latin Modern Mono}

\DeclareRobustCommand\lcseries{\fontseries{lc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlc}{\lcseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\lbseries{\fontseries{lb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlb}{\lbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\lseries{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textl}{\lseries}

\DeclareRobustCommand\propseries{\fontseries{prop}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textprop}{\propseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\proplseries{\fontseries{propl}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textpropl}{\proplseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\proplbseries{\fontseries{proplb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textproplb}{\proplbseries}



\newcommand\textsample{ABC abc}
\newcommand\textsamplex{--}
\newcommand\textsamplec[1]{\ball~The cat sat on the mat and the Quick Brown Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog. iiiii mmmmm ({\propseries\color{blue}#1}). }


\begin{document}

\rmfamily

rmfamily


\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]},
    row{odd}={bg=blue!5},
    row{1}={bg=blue!12},
    cell{3}{1}={halign={r},font=\small},
    cell{6}{1}={halign={r},font=\small},
}
Shape 
& Regular
& Bold
& SC-Regular
& SC-Bold
\\
\hline
Upright
& \textsample
& \bfseries \textsample
& \scshape \textsample
& \scshape \textsamplex
\\
Demi
& \textsamplex
& \scseries \textsample
& \scshape \textsamplex
& \scseries \textsamplex
\\
Italic
& \itshape \textsample
& \itshape \bfseries \textsample
& \itshape \textsamplex
& \itshape \bfseries \textsamplex
\\
Slanted
& \slshape \textsample
& \slshape \bfseries \textsample
& \slshape \scshape \textsample
& \slshape \scshape \textsamplex
\\
Demi Slanted
& \slshape \textsamplex
& \slshape \scseries \textsample
& \slshape \scshape \textsamplex
& \slshape \scshape  \textsamplex
\\
Swash
& \swshape \textsample
& \swshape  \textsamplex
& \swshape  \textsamplex
& \swshape  \textsamplex
\\
Swash Slanted
& \swslshape \textsample
& \swslshape  \textsamplex
& \swslshape  \textsamplex
& \swslshape   \textsamplex
\\
Unslanted
& \unslshape \textsample
& \unslshape  \textsamplex
& \unslshape  \textsamplex
& \unslshape   \textsamplex
\\
\end{tblr}


\bigskip
\noindent
{\textsamplec{<rmfamily>}}
{\bfseries\textsamplec{bfseries}}
{\scshape\textsamplec{scshape}}
{\scseries\textsamplec{scseries}}

\bigskip
\noindent 
{\itshape\textsamplec{itshape}}
{\itshape\bfseries\textsamplec{itshape bfseries}}
{\slshape\textsamplec{slshape}}
{\slshape\bfseries\textsamplec{slshape bfseries}}
{\slshape\scshape\textsamplec{slshape scshape}}
{\slshape\scseries\textsamplec{slshape scseries}}


\bigskip
\noindent 
{\swshape\textsamplec{swshape}}
{\swslshape\textsamplec{swslshape}}
{\unslshape\textsamplec{unslshape}}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\sffamily

sffamily


\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]},
    row{odd}={bg=blue!5},
    row{1}={bg=blue!12},
    cell{3}{1}={halign={r},font=\small},
    cell{6}{1}={halign={r},font=\small},
}
Shape 
& Regular
& Bold
& SC-Regular
& SC-Bold
\\
\hline
Upright
& \textsample
& \bfseries \textsample
&  \textsamplex
& \textsamplex
\\
Demi
& \textsamplex
& \scseries \textsample
&  \textsamplex
& \scseries \textsamplex
\\
Italic
&  \textsamplex
&  \bfseries \textsamplex
&  \textsamplex
&  \bfseries \textsamplex
\\
Oblique
& \slshape \textsample
& \slshape \bfseries \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape  \textsamplex
\\
Demi Oblique
& \slshape \textsamplex
& \slshape \scseries \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape   \textsamplex
\\
Quot
& \quotshape \textsample
& \quotshape \bfseries \textsample
& \quotshape \textsamplex
& \quotshape \bfseries \textsamplex
\\
Quot Oblique
& \quotslshape \textsample
& \quotslshape \bfseries \textsample
& \quotslshape \textsamplex
& \quotslshape \bfseries \textsamplex
\\
\end{tblr}


\bigskip
\noindent 
{\textsamplec{<sffamily>}}
{\bfseries\textsamplec{bfseries}}
{\scseries\textsamplec{scseries}}

\bigskip
\noindent 
{\slshape\textsamplec{slshape}}
{\slshape\bfseries\textsamplec{slshape bfseries}}
{\slshape\scseries\textsamplec{slshape scseries}}

\bigskip
\noindent 
{\quotshape\textsamplec{quotshape}}
{\quotshape\bfseries\textsamplec{quotshape bfseries}}
{\quotslshape\textsamplec{quotslshape}}
{\quotslshape\bfseries\textsamplec{quotslshape bfseries}}




%--------------------------------------------------
\newpage
\ttfamily

ttfamily

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]Q[l]},
    row{odd}={bg=blue!5},
    row{1}={bg=blue!12},
%   cell{3}{1}={halign={r},font=\small},
%   cell{6}{1}={halign={r},font=\small},
}
Shape 
& Regular
& Bold
& SC-Regular
& SC-Bold
\\
\hline
Upright
& \textsample
&  \textsamplex
&  \scshape \textsample
& \textsamplex
\\
Italic
& \itshape \textsample
&  \textsamplex
&  \textsamplex
&  \textsamplex
\\
Oblique
& \slshape \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape  \scshape \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
\\
Light Condensed
& \lcseries \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape   \textsamplex
\\
LC Oblique
& \slshape \lcseries \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape   \textsamplex
\\
Light Upright
&  \lseries \textsample
&  \lbseries \textsample
&   \textsamplex
&    \textsamplex
\\
Light Oblique
& \slshape \lseries \textsample
& \slshape \lbseries \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape   \textsamplex
\\
Prop Upright
& \propseries \textsample
&  \propseries \textsamplex
&   \textsamplex
&    \textsamplex
\\
Prop Oblique
& \slshape \propseries \textsample
& \slshape \propseries \textsamplex
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape   \textsamplex
\\
Prop Lt Upright
&  \proplseries \textsample
&  \proplbseries \textsample
&   \textsamplex
&    \textsamplex
\\
Prop Lt Oblique
& \slshape \proplseries \textsample
& \slshape \proplbseries \textsample
& \slshape  \textsamplex
& \slshape   \textsamplex
\\
\end{tblr}



\bigskip
\noindent 
{\textsamplec{<ttfamily>}}
{\scshape\textsamplec{scshape}}
{\itshape\textsamplec{itshape}}
{\slshape\textsamplec{slshape}}
{\slshape\scshape\textsamplec{slshape scshape}}


\bigskip
\noindent 
{\lcseries\textsamplec{lcseries}}
{\slshape \lcseries\textsamplec{slshape lcseries}}
{\lseries\textsamplec{lseries}}
{\lbseries\textsamplec{lbseries}}
{\slshape\lseries\textsamplec{slshape lseries}}
{\slshape\lbseries\textsamplec{slshape lbseries}}


\bigskip
\noindent 
{\propseries\textsamplec{propseries}}
{\proplseries\textsamplec{proplseries}}
{\proplbseries\textsamplec{lbpropseries}}
{\slshape\propseries\textsamplec{slshape propseries}}
{\slshape\proplseries\textsamplec{slshape proplseries}}
{\slshape\proplbseries\textsamplec{slshape proplbseries}}






\end{document}
```